# A footballer who doesn't pass the ball

Tags: word-request

Could someone please tell me what we call a football(soccer) player who doesn't pass the ball and ignores other players at good positions.

I think about  **"Soloist"** but I am not sure if it works for sport too.

Comment: "Soloist" would probably be understood but it's not a very good analogy. A soloist in music isn't being selfish or depriving others of opportunities: they're just doing their job of playing the most significant part in the piece.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could say he is [*hogging the ball*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hog).

> **hog**
>   *verb* (hogs, hogging, hogged)
>   [with object]
>
> 1. *informal* Take or use most or all of (something) in an unfair or selfish way: *he never hogged the limelight*

This usage is very common to describe the situation you mentioned, and you hear it a lot in sports commentary. In US English you could say *ball hog*, but this is less idiomatic in UK English (although people would certainly understand what you meant), where in my experience it is more common to describe what he is *doing* (hogging the ball) than what he *is*.

Alternatively, you could simply say he is *not a [team player](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/team-player)*.

Comment: I've heard the expression in BrE that such a person "wants a ball of his own".

Answer (score 14):

Back when I played, we called that kind of person a "ball hog."

> A **ball hog** is a derisive term for a basketball player that handles the ball exclusively to the point of impairing the team. 
> <sub>Source: “Ball hog”
>   [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_hog)</sub>

Comment: When I was young we would say, "He was ball greedy."

Answer (score 3):

I would use **greedy** but I would also recognise *ball hog*.

Answer (score 2):

*Hog* is the term generally used, but a term that is gaining traction is *'Playstation' Footballer*,  which alludes to doing something in a way that is more elaborate than necessary (for example, holding onto the ball too long, rather than using teammates).

Comment: A person who does something in a way that is more elaborate than necessary is generally called a "hot dog" in AmE.  One may also say that such a person is "hotdogging".

Comment: **Warning**: Do not google _"hot dogging"_.